# Zxing : Unable to Scan Small UPC codes

Tags: android, zxing

Am currently trying out zxing to develop a MultiFormat Barcode reading supporting android platform, To get Started have downladed zxing 1.7 and builded.

It works fine with EAN format codes and QR Codes, But It fails to scan a Barcode when it comes to real scanning of products which has small UPC barcodes.

Is this a problem with device?

Am Testing it on my Samsung GT-S5570, Android Version 2.2.1, With Autofocus enabled Camera 3.1 MP.

Kindly advice.

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Open a bug report in the Zxing issue tracker and provide them all the info they might want starting with the image of barcode itself.

Comment: Hi Plaes,Thanks for your prompt response. I don't really see it as a bug as I can decode barcodes provided with the downloaded zxing package folder "zxing-1990\core\test\data\blackbox". As those images are clear so the detection and decoding goes accurately. But Real products I mean, Lets say a product on my Desk e.g.., Cigar pack which has a Small Barcode on it. So is it some thing with Camera Resolution ?

Comment: You might want to look at a commercial barcode scanner such as [Scandit](http://www.scandit.com/). They are far better at recognizing barcodes under poor light conditions, handling small barcodes and supporting fixed focus cameras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can scan EAN barcodes, but not small UPC barcodes, it is probably because the camera can't get enough detail to distinguish the barcode from the background. Here are some things you could try:

- Hold the camera closer to, or further away from, the barcode. Too close, and the auto focus  mechanism is unable to compensate. Too far away, and the barcode becomes too small for detection.
- Use more light. ZXing can activate the flash-light on some phones, but not all. If the lightning conditions are too poor, the contrast between the background and the barcode becomes too small.
- Try with a different phone, with different/better camera.

Comment: Good advice though typically the problem is people holding the barcode too *close*, not far.

Comment: Hi Mizard, Yes that's what am wondering is there any specific camera resolution? Was told zxing will scan a barcode if the camera has an autofocus mechanism. Presently am trying out with 3.1 MP camera which has an autofocus mechanism.

Comment: Hi Mizard, Yes Its all about camera resolution, Have tried using with Galaxy Tab, works well. Would have been better if zxing forum lists all compatible devices which it can supports.

Comment: @Samuel actually the camera resolution does not matter. It is using the preview stream which is much less than a megapixel. This is still enough to scan. We support all Android 1.5+ devices