# Unable to scan QRCode via zxing client

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am unable to scan a QR Code having dark background(dark pink) with lighter QRcode(light pink) on it. I have integrated the zxing barcode scanner in my application to scan codes.. It works perfect for lighter background and dark QRcodes.

I tried this using the default zxing barcode scanner application. But it could not scan such kind of codes.

Following is the QRCode I am trying to scan,
[image]

Please suggest some solution.

Thankyou.

Comment: Go thorough this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103279/zxing-unable-to-scan-small-upc-codes.This may solve your problem.

Comment: You might also consider posting a sample QR code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Yes I have edited my question with the QRCode I am trying to scan. Please have a look.

Comment: I suspect that you will need greater contrast to get reliable results. Bear in mind that camera quality varies a lot between devices, and so even if some devices could handle this barcode, others might not.

Comment: Yes I understand your point. I did scan the same QRCode with Samsung Galaxy S3(Higher end device), Samsung Galaxy Nexus (Higher end),Samsung Ace (Middle range), LG Optimus(Middle Range).. But no luck.. Are you referring to the contrast in the QRCode?

Comment: @GautamM. Hi, did you find solution for this problem(color inverted QR Code)?

Answer (score 1):

Contrast of QR Code you included should be enough for most cameras. Problem here is that the ZXing library does not support inverted QR Codes. It only supports dark codes on light background.

To add this support, you need to invert the image yourself. You can use some code similar to this one:
http://www.androidsnippets.com/how-to-invert-bitmap-color

Of course, you will need to integrate the ZXing by including the library to accomplish this, not just by Intent (I don't know how you're doing it now) so you can modify some code.

You can add the code to invert the bitmap in the method **decode**(byte[], int, int) of class **DecodeHandler**.

Comment: The library supports inverted barcodes just fine, in the LuminanceSource implementation -- it's just that they're not part of the core of the ISO spec, so it doesn't look for them in the Android app by default. There's a setting that enables it though. Although there it's using the camera driver to invert the image...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment. Can you please tell what are the different settings that need to be done to solve this issue..

Comment: @GautamM. Did you find solution for inverted QR Code?